# Concatenate Excel File Sheets in Pandas, Exporting Large Pandas Data Frame to new Excel files every 1 mill rows in CSV format. Automation?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have an excel file that has multiple sheets. I am attempting to put all the sheets into one file. So, first I read the file into a Jupyter Notebook and concatenated the sheets into 1 data frame. It looks like the .to_excel method could make the single excel file.

How can I get pandas to export it into a CSV instead of an xlsx? Also, is there a way to have it break at the 1 millionth row and begin a new Excel file for the next 1 million (since Excel has a row limit)?

To another point, wondering how to automate this process? I'm assuming a for loop would be the function I'd want to use for the process in full.

Lastly, saving it in an xlsx file is not allowing me to open the file. Also, when I convert it to a csv it comes back with scrambled text that looks nothing like my file.

my code currently:

```
pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

Pipeline_df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('PandasToExcel.xlsx', sheet_name = None), ignore_index = True)
Pipeline_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Pipeline_output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
Pipeline_writer.save()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can use to_csv directly and calculate chunks to write. There may be library to this already, but I've used this.

```
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({'dataseet':range(1,1000500)})

num_rows = df.shape[0]
chunk_size = 1000000
chunks = math.ceil(num_rows / chunk_size)

for i in range(chunks):
    dftowrite = df[chunk_size*i : chunk_size*(i+1)]
    dftowrite.to_csv('filechunk_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: This code worked but the file output is just a single row that counts from 1 - 1million. I'm needing to take the xlsx file that I have. Concat the sheets in that file and export them to a new csv file. But it will need to be 1 million+ rows of data at a time due to Excel limitations.. I must be missing something here. I must admit that I'm not versed enough with Python to interpret your code.

Comment: You said you had a concatenated dataframe??? just use your df instead of the example provided (as I don't have access to your data for testing).

Comment: ok I did this instead: df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_df[0:1000000])    df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_df[1000001:1016385])          df1.to_csv('new_example', index = False) 
        df2.to_csv('new_example2', index = False) .                                                                   
Output was scrambled w gibberish. So, went to where files were stored (C-drive) and "open with" in notepad. Saved notepads as CSVs. The concern now is how to make it automated? A function that takes the Excel file, concatenates the sheets to a DF, exports the concatenated DF to CSV. At 1milli rows, a new CSV starts

Comment: if you don't know how to read an excel file and concatenate a df, that's a new question you should open. problems opening csv: you didn't put .csv in your file name. I suggest in general that you spend some time searching stackoverflow  for your needs. everything you are asking about has several examples that are similar.

Comment: There's a character limit. Trying to explain all details as a newbie is difficult. But, I have simplified my issue down. At this point, I only need to build the function to execute my work. Right now I can read and concat my Excel file's sheets. Then, I am able to split the concat file into multiple df's by 1 million. Then, turn the df's into CSVs. However, when I put this into a function, it is not working due to an error in my function's parameter. Here is my function: def automate_excel(excel_automated):            I have tried to put (excel_auto.xlsx) or even use " " and it's being flagged

Comment: Here is my current code altogether:  def automate_excel(excel_automated):
    excel_file = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Excel_to_Python_Pipeline_Exercise.xlsx', sheet_name = None), ignore_index = True)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(NewPipe_df[0:1000000])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(NewPipe_df[1000001:2000000])
    df1.to_csv('new_example1', index = False)
    df2.to_csv('new_example2', index = False)
automate_excel()